# Is there a shortcut key for windows explorer navigation input?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I want to be able to to quickly go to the top of the window and type the location to which I want to navigate. Is there a shortcut key for this? If not can it be created?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in Internet Explorer, and most other web browsers, the shortcut you're looking for is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works for Windows Explorer and all (read all common) browsers to go to address bar.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to set the keyboard focus to the address bar in Windows Explorer:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to focus the address bar
- <kbd>F4</kbd> to focus the address bar and drop it down as well
- <kbd>F6</kbd> to “Tab” between Explorer panes (usually between the file list and the address bar)

Windows keyboards shortcuts: [[1]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583) [[2]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) [[3]](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/KeyboardSearch_XP.aspxhttp://www.microsoft.com/enable/products/KeyboardSearch_XP.aspx) [[4]](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/keys_general.mspx?mfr=true) [[5]](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers I've used accept <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>(lower-case-L) for jumping to the "location" bar.  I don't know if that works in this case or not, but worth a try.

Comment: No, that (somewhat surprisingly) doesn’t work for Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Synetech  I wonder if that's something Microsoft broke on purpose...

Comment: No, there’s nothing broken about it, they just chose not to include that hotkey in Windows Explorer when `Alt+D` does the same thing. Even in web browsers it is redundant.